# MeteorJS: Consuming XML API

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am working on a small app that will be consuming an XML data-source. I am slightly confused on how to populate the handlebar template with the returned data. It would be nice to try to offload the XML to Mongo, however, the API call isn't 100% consistent in what it returns every-time (as the information in the call could have changed since the last call was made).

Main.html

```
<head>
  <title>FastTrack</title>
  <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&sensor=false">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="header">
          {{> header}}

          <div id="map-container">
            {{> gmap}}
          </div>

          <div class="row" id="map-footer">
            {{> selector}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      {{> jobs}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

jobs.html

```
<template name="jobs">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {{#each job}}
      Howdy
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

jobs.js (just for testing):

```
Template.jobs.rendered = function() {
  return jobs = [{
    job: {
      foo: "bar"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how you're collecting the XML data (HTTP call, or some other method would be helpful )

Answer (score 1):

You may populate the template's `data` parameter in the `created` callback:

```
Template.jobs.created = function() {
  this.data.jobs = [
    {job: {...}},
    {job: {...}},
    {job: {...}},  
  ];
};
```

Comment: If I `console.log` the `this.data` it comes back as undefined... here is my JS file: https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/afa0c27761c0af7dfc59